# BigCommerce API - get customers by ip

Tags: api, bigcommerce

The Customer object has a field called `registration_ip_address`, however the Resource doesn't allow us to do a `get_customers{registration_ip_address: "xxx.yy.zz"}` to find the customers by their IP address.  Is this an intentional feature or is it just an oversight?  With OAuth the API call needs to have the specific store hash combination anyway, so I don't see there being a security issue with the new API version.

Comment: you want to get a  customer by ip_address using the api?, I only know this only accept customer id

Comment: You can do a get_customers() call with a bunch of different filter methods and it will return all customers which match those filters.  Registration IP address is just one of the Customer fields that isn't a filter yet.
`/stores/{store_hash}/v2/customers?first_name={value}` for example will return all customers with their first name = value
See [link](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/customers) for more details.